# Illegal offset type laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7

I want to update 4 fields with a same value, so I have done this:

```
UpdateModel::where('model_id', $id)->update([['is_1_ans', 'is_2_ans', 'is_3_ans', 'is_4_ans'] => 1]);
```

but I laravel giving me this error;

**Illegal offset type**

I know I'm doing wrong but I want to know how to update multiple fields with same value if needed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this is out of the box, but you can do this to fill the values to the keys:

```php
// The keys you want to update
$keys = ['is_1_ans', 'is_2_ans', 'is_3_ans', 'is_4_ans'];

// We use array_fill_keys to fill "1" to all the keys above
$updates = array_fill_keys($keys, 1);

// This will result in
// $updates = ['is_1_ans' => 1, 'is_2_ans' => 1, 'is_3_ans' => 1, 'is_4_ans' => 1];

// Then you do your usual updates ;)
UpdateModel::where('model_id', $id)->update($updates);
```

See [array_fill_keys documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill-keys.php).